# Kotlin String compare with == not working?

Tags: string, kotlin, compare

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. This is a debug run. "year" and "prevYear" are both strings and have different values as shown, but somehow, the inside of this if statement block is still executing. Debugger steps into the block.

[Debug run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GITC9.png)

```
    // Get previous year
    val date = Date() // Current date
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.US)
    val intPrevYear = format.format(date).toInt()-1
    val prevYear: String = intPrevYear.toString()

    for (entry in _entryList)
    {
        val year: String = entry.date.substring(6)
        if (year == prevYear) // Found a match
        {
            //entryDao.delete(entry)
            var a = 0
            a += 1
            a += 3
        }
    }
```

I changed the compare to != and the debugger still steps into the block

Comment: Perhaps the compiler (or JVM) determined that the body of your if-statement has no side-effects (since all it does is modify an `Int` local to the if statement body), and therefore decided to always execute the body and skip the string comparision.

Comment: That definitely looks strange. Try to cleanup your project and reinstall the app. Maybe somehow it uses a different code than we see. Explanation by @Michael also seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Michael is on the right track. I changed the code to keep a count of the number of times the block executed and sent it back to the UI to send a Toast. It is behaving correctly now. Strange, but a good learning point. Thanks for the replies all!

Comment: If you are motivated to get the answer, you can use smali/apktool tool to disassemble the apk code and verify what's really there.